# cant execute codes after calling launch(GUI.class) in main()

Tags: java, javafx

I am writing a snake game on javaFX 12.0.1 and jdk 12.0.1 and i wrote a class GUI which extends javafx.application.Application in which i made a scene with Anchorpane which has an HBox for buttons and Canvas for drawing, then i call the GUI on my Main class which has the main method. 
I wrote some print statements to debug my codes but realized that whatever i write after the javafx.application.Application.launch() method dont execute

I tried changing the precedence to launch at the end of the main but some of my codes depend on the start() method to execute first and i get null pointer exception

Here is my Main class:

```
public class Main {
    private static int score = 10;
    private static ArrayList<SnakeBlock> snakeBlocks = new ArrayList<>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        snakeBlocks.add(new SnakeBlock(300, 200));
        System.out.println(snakeBlocks.size());
        //Launch the GUI
        javafx.application.Application.launch(GUI.class);
        System.out.println("Program launched");
        new Thread(new SnakeDraw()).start();
    }

    public static int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public static void setScore(int score) {
        Main.score = score;
    }

    public static int getSnakeBlocksSize() {
        return snakeBlocks.size();
    }

    public static ArrayList<SnakeBlock> getSnakeBlocks() {
        return snakeBlocks;
    }
}
```

And heres the GUI class:

```
public class GUI extends Application {
    private static Text scoreText;
    private static Canvas canvas;
    private int width = 600, height = 400;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        StackPane holder = new StackPane(addCanvas());
        holder.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#3d494a");
        borderPane.setTop(addAnchorPane());
        borderPane.setCenter(holder);

        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, width, height);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("/style.css");

        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        stage.setTitle("Snake");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public AnchorPane addAnchorPane() {
        AnchorPane anchorpane = new AnchorPane();
        anchorpane.setId("anchorpane");
        anchorpane.getStyleClass().add("anchorpane");

        //reset Button
        Button buttonReset = new Button("reset");
        buttonReset.setStyle("-fx-font: 22 arial; -fx-base: #b6e7c9;");
        buttonReset.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                Main.setScore(0);
                GUI.scoreText.setText(String.format("Score: %d", Main.getScore()));
                canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().clearRect(0,0,1000, 1000);
            }
        });

        //Quit Button
        Button buttonQuit = new Button("Quit");
        buttonQuit.setStyle("-fx-font: 22 arial; -fx-base: #b6e7c9;");
        buttonQuit.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        scoreText = new Text(10, 10, String.format("Score: %d", Main.getScore()));
        scoreText.setFont(Font.font("arial", 34));
        HBox scoreBox = new HBox(scoreText);
        HBox hb = new HBox();
        hb.setPadding(new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2));
        hb.setSpacing(10);
        hb.getChildren().addAll(buttonReset, buttonQuit);

        anchorpane.getChildren().addAll(scoreBox, hb);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(hb, 8.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(hb, 5.0);

        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(scoreBox, 5.0);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(scoreBox, 8.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(scoreBox, 4.0);

        return anchorpane;
    }

    public Canvas addCanvas() {
        canvas = new Canvas(600,400);
        return canvas;
    }

    public static Canvas getCanvas() {
        return canvas;
    }
}
```

I also have a SnakeBlock class and a runnable SnakeDraw class but theyre not complete yet so i left them out

Is launch() like a loop which executes until end and prevents other codes after it to execute or did I mess up anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in a JavaFX program, your main method should only look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
}
```

**Source here:** https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String...)

This is because in a JavaFX program, the main method acts like a failover.  Docs specifically state this:

````
 * The main() method is ignored in correctly deployed JavaFX application.
 * main() serves only as fallback in case the application can not be
 * launched through deployment artifacts```
````

Comment: I forget add this syntax: ``Application.launch(MyApp.class, args);``

Comment: thanks a lot i didn't know about that since I just started learning javafx